# How to load a Windows icon using a pixel buffer?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, icons

I'm trying to create a Windows-compatible icon using a pixel buffer. The Surface class loads an image and saves it as an unsigned int array internally (0xRRGGBB).

I'm trying to create an icon like so:

```
Surface m_Test("Data/Interface/CursorTest.png");
HICON result = CreateIconFromResourceEx( (PBYTE)m_Test.GetBuffer(), 
                                         m_Test.GetWidth() * m_Test.GetHeight(), 
                                         FALSE, 
                                         0, 
                                         24, 
                                         24, 
                                         LR_DEFAULTCOLOR
);
```

However, `result` is always `NULL`. I can't find anywhere what data format `CreateIconFromResourceEx` expects.

Ultimately I want to load an icon from an external file, without using resource files.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I figured it out! The final codez:

```
// m_Cursors is an array of images coming from an image strip
Pixel* buffer   = m_Cursors[i]->GetBuffer();
int width       = m_Cursors[i]->GetWidth();
int height      = m_Cursors[i]->GetHeight();

HDC dc_andmask = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
HBITMAP cur_andmask = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, width, height);
HBITMAP hOldAndMaskBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(dc_andmask, cur_andmask);

HDC dc_xormask = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
HBITMAP cur_xormask = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, width, height);
HBITMAP hOldXorMaskBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(dc_xormask, cur_xormask);

for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
        Pixel currpix = buffer[x + y * width];

        // the images use the alpha channel for transparancy
        if ((currpix & 0xFF000000) == 0
        {
            // transparant
            SetPixel(dc_andmask, x, y, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            SetPixel(dc_xormask, x, y, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        }
        else
        {
            COLORREF curr = RGB(currpix & 0xFF0000 >> 16, currpix & 0x00FF00 >> 8, currpix & 0x0000FF);

            // opaque
            SetPixel(dc_andmask, x, y, RGB(0, 0, 0));
            SetPixel(dc_xormask, x, y, curr);
        }
    }
}

// i don't know why this has to be done, but it fixes things
// so who cares (b ")b
SelectObject(dc_andmask, hOldAndMaskBitmap);
SelectObject(dc_xormask, hOldXorMaskBitmap);

DeleteObject(dc_xormask);
DeleteObject(dc_andmask);

ICONINFO temp = { FALSE, m_OffsetX[i], m_OffsetY[i], cur_andmask, cur_xormask };
m_CursorIDs[i] = CreateIconIndirect(&temp);
```

Comment: Avoid SetPixel if possible. That's awfully slow. Try creating a DIB section using your raw bytes as source (if you setup your BITMAPHEADER correctly, Windows will take your pixel format directly).

Comment: It doesn't really matter, this is all done at initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`CreateIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648059%28VS.85%29.aspx) if you want to pass the raw bytes data from the AND and XOR mask.

If instead you want to be able to use `HBITMAP`s, you can use [`CreateIconIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648062%28VS.85%29.aspx). Using this API, you can can even [create icons with an alpha channel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318876) if you so desire.

Comment: In your specific case you'll want to create a 24-bit DIB section pointing to your Surface class' internal array and pass that to CreateIconIndirect. (Destroy the HBITMAP afterwards)

Comment: @Koro Can you provide the detail example codes for create icon from bytes data?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this class taken from [koders.com](http://www.koders.com/c/fid55D004F52EB90C37C70A73DBA579A1D63622E466.aspx)

It provides methods for

```
LPICONRESOURCE ReadIconFromICOFile( LPCTSTR szFileName )
```

and

```
LPICONRESOURCE ReadIconFromEXEFile( LPCTSTR szFileName )
```